# Textbox Multiline MaxLength

Tags: development, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

I have created an Multiline  textbox and need to define the MaxLength on it. I have read that we can use javascript to solve it but since I am new in JavaScript so maybe someone can help me?

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxContents" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
```

If Someone send me and javascript to solve it were should i put the script and what should i also write in my textbox, Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I down voted your question because first search in google returns [this link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26179/Check-maxlength-of-multiline-textbox-in-javascript).

Comment: Agreed, you are better off googling for an answer, such as "javascript multiline", and you will SEE you answers, rather than waiting for a reply. StackExchange is for answers that are NOT answered by a simple Google search.